# React updating array state

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update an array state, ok it updates the state correctly if I checked the state in the react dev tool, but the logged message is the state without the last update.
If I use array.push to update the state, it logs the updated state

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU2lC.png)

Comment: Updating a state in react is an asynchronous process .
Please read more about state and state updation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setGoalsArray` will not update the variable for the current scope but only for the next render.

Therefore you will need to create an effect which triggers once `goalsArray` is changed e.g.:

```
  useEffect(() => console.log(goalsArray), [goalsArray])
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html